# Sorting an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$employeeAges = array();
$employeeAges["Lisa"] = "28";
$employeeAges["Jack"] = "16";
$employeeAges["Ryan"] = "35";
$employeeAges["Rachel"] = "46";
$employeeAges["Grace"] = "34";
sort($employeeAges);
foreach( $employeeAges as $name => $age){
    echo "Name: $name, Age: $age <br />";
}
```

When i sort the $employeeAges it prints out this, without the names of the employee's

```
Name: 0, Age: 16 
Name: 1, Age: 28 
Name: 2, Age: 34 
Name: 3, Age: 35 
Name: 4, Age: 46
```

How would i get it to print out the names as well? I'm not sure why it changes :S

Comment: easy `asort` http://php.net/asort

Comment: cmorrissey solved it! thanks, totally forgot about asort!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure to search, before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asort($array)`;

It will do the work for you.